# How to reload the page content with ajax dynamicly, without head reloading on Drupal?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reload

Hi Drupal web developers! I have a problem, which must be solved, but I had never been to work with ajax page reloading. The page head can not be reloaded and some div blocks (I gave them `iscritical="true"` and `criticalid="someidword"` tags). So, I wrote this JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
    var href_ = ($.trim($(this).attr('href'))).toLowerCase();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    if((href.substr(0, 1) != '#') && (href.substr(0, 11) != 'javascript:')){
        IG_AJAX_PAGELOAD(href);
        return false;
    }
});
});

function IG_AJAX_PAGELOAD(href){
$.get(href, function(res){
    if((strpos(res.toLowerCase(), '<body>', 0) == false) || (strpos(res.toLowerCase(), '</body>', 0) == false))
        return false;
    var critical_block_html_array = new Array();
    $('div[iscritical="true"]').each(function(){
        critical_block_html_array[$(this).attr('criticalid')] = $(this).html();
    });

    console.log(document.ready);

    document.body.innerHTML = res.substr(strpos(res.toLowerCase(), '<body>', 0) + 7, (strpos(res.toLowerCase(), '</body>', 0) - 1 - (strpos(res.toLowerCase(), '<body>', 0) + 7)));
    for(var cur in critical_block_html_array){
        if($('div[criticalid="'+cur+'"]').length < 1) continue;
        $('div[criticalid="'+cur+'"]').html(critical_block_html_array[cur]);
    }

    $(document).ready();
    $(window).load();

    console.log('page loaded successfully');
});
return false;
}
```

and it works. But, when the page content become reloaded, JavaScript codes, which are inside the `<head>` tag are not work, how they must work if the page is just loaded. I try to run the fake "page load and window load" events, but nothing wants to work. What should I do this code to work perfectly? May be, you know some modules?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `return false;` is your problem. And You want to fire the event on every link on the page!?

Tell us why you need code like this, and we try to help.

And don't forget to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to your code.